# match only words (no guarantee of spaces)

Tags: python, regex, string

I was wondering if I could get some help on this.

I'm trying to match all the words but I there are some reqs:

1. a word is anything valid within a parens (like in a function), but the function itself should not be matched
2. a word may have a numeric at the end or the start
3. there is no guarantee of a single space (or ANY space other than some operators)

e.g: `y ~ word1+word2 - 3word:word4        ** word5 + Function(word6)`

The return should be of `["y", "word1", "word2", "3word", "word4", "word5", "word6"]`.

So far I've got `regexp = "(\d?[a-zA-Z]+\d?)+"` which matches ALMOST all except there is an erroneous `Function` in the list.

A full runnable example:

```py
import string
from typing import List
import re
q_str = "y ~ word1+word2 - 3word:word4        ** word5 + Function(word6)"

regexp = "(\d?[a-zA-Z]+\d?)+"

re.findall(regexp, q_str)
```

Comment: Why should `Function` fail?  Which one of your requirements does it not pass?

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that. I've updated rule 1 to reflect that. Thank you for catching that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\b\d?[a-zA-Z]+\d?\b(?!\s*\()
```

The pattern matches

- `\b\d?[a-zA-Z]+\d?\b` Match 1+ chars a-zA-Z between an optional digit at the left and right
- `(?!\s*\()` Negative lookahead, to assert not optional whitespace chars followed by a `(`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5ZMR8Q/1) or a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/HSouB3).

Example code

```
import re

pattern = r"\b\d?[a-zA-Z]+\d?\b(?!\s*\()"
s = "y ~ word1+word2 - 3word:word4        ** word5 + Function(word6)"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['y', 'word1', 'word2', '3word', 'word4', 'word5', 'word6']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a "negative lookahead": fail if followed by a paren.  That's the (?!():

```
regexp = "(\d?[a-zA-Z]+\d?)+(?!\()"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
regex = r"(\w+)(?!\()\W+"
```

Matches everything in your example.

EDIT: Did not see that you did not want words that preceded a parentheses, added a negative look-ahead to catch that as well.

`\w` Matches any letter, digit or underscore. Equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_].

`\W` Matches anything other than a letter, digit or underscore. Equivalent to [^a-zA-Z0-9_]

You can see the results here:
https://regex101.com/r/N1kdf1/1